# Selenium presence_of_element_located look for children of an element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I was wondering if it's possible to look for children of an element with the `presence_of_element_located` function. I know I could just use the entire path, but that would make my code more confusing due to it's nature. My code would look something like this (much more complicated but this is the important bit):

```
currentEl = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("//*[@id='2']"))
func(currentEl)

def func(currentEl):
    #Wait for the element to appear
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10, poll_frequency=0.001, ignored_exceptions = (StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException)).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((currentEl, (By.CLASS_NAME, "class")))
    )

    return
```

So basically I'm trying to wait for the child element with the class name "class" of the WebElement named currentEl. I'we tried many things and I'd hate to resort to just using the entire path.

Answer (score 0):

Child element with class name `className` can be located by relative XPath `.//*[contains(@class,'className')]` or with relative CSS Selector `.className`.
So, I think your code can be modified to be

```py
currentEl = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("//*[@id='2']"))
func(currentEl)

def func(currentEl):
    #Wait for the element to appear
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10, poll_frequency=0.001, ignored_exceptions = (StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException)).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((currentEl, By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@class,'className')]")))
    return
```

Or

```py
currentEl = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("//*[@id='2']"))
func(currentEl)

def func(currentEl):
    #Wait for the element to appear
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10, poll_frequency=0.001, ignored_exceptions = (StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException)).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((currentEl, By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".className")))
    return
```

**UPD**
I'm not sure the structure above will work.
What you can do is to pass correct locator to existing `expected_conditions`, as following:

```py
locator1 = (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='2']//*[contains(@class,'className')]")
locator2 = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#2 .className")

def wait_for_child_element(locator):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))

#call the method above with arguments:
wait_for_child_element(locator1)
wait_for_child_element(locator2)
```

Comment: I get an error saying: "TypeError: find_element() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given"

Comment: I did not change the line where 'find_element()' I method is called.

Comment: It points within the function. currentEl is obtained correctly.

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 10, poll_frequency=0.001, ignored_exceptions = (StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException)).until(
File "/home/...", line 86, in until
value = method(self._driver)
  File "/home/.../expected_conditions.py", line 64, in _predicate
    return driver.find_element(*locator)
TypeError: find_element() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: This is what you using here. I'm not sure your initial construction `WebDriverWait(driver, 10, poll_frequency=0.001, ignored_exceptions = (StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException)).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((currentEl, (By.CLASS_NAME, "class"))))` is correct. I just tried to give a correct locator. I'll try to give better solution

Comment: No that construction is false. It works if I just use it like: `WebDriverWait(driver, 10, poll_frequency=0.001, ignored_exceptions = (StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException)).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ("path"))))`, but that make my code far more complex in the long run, because the parent element's path constantly changes, only the child's path relatively to the parent stays the same.

Comment: Your edit would work, but the issue is that the path of the parent isn't given. What I have is a WebElement. If I could somehow get it's path that wold work great.

Comment: I see. Let's see, maybe somebody will be able to do that.